# How to disable /Oy (Frame-Pointer Omission) in Release version in vc9

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction

I turned off FPO manually(/Oy–) in vs2008 ,but it has no effect and my code still omits frame pointers in  release version.
BTW i also turned off /GL as micosoft said there was a bug bwtween /GL and /O2 [enter link description here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/433201/vc-2008-express-oy-compiler-switch-doesnt-work-together-with-o1-o2-ox)
every thing was OK when i tried to compile the same project with vs2010, ,but i need to make it work in vs2008,does any one know how to fix this? thanks!!!

Comment: EBP is still omitted in leaf functions.  The kind that doesn't call any functions itself.  Be more specific about what you see if that is not a match.